# Mock a function in a streamlit app during e2e testing

Tags: python, testing, pytest, playwright, streamlit

I have a e2e testing framework for running my streamlit app but am having trouble mocking some functions that make SOAP requests. Where in my framework should I be adding the mocked function?

```
import pytest
from playwright.sync_api import Page, expect
from contextlib import contextmanager
from time import sleep
import subprocess

@pytest.fixture(scope="module", autouse=True)
def before_module():
    """Runs the streamlit app before the test module"""

    with run_streamlit():
        yield


@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def before_test(page: Page):
    """Reloads the page before each test function"""

    page.goto("localhost:8501")


@contextmanager
def run_streamlit():
    """Run the streamlit app at entrypoint.py on default streamlit port 8501"""

    p = subprocess.Popen(
        [
            "python",
            "-m",
            "streamlit",
            "run",
            "entrypoint.py",
            "--server.port",
            "8501",
            "--server.headless",
            "true",
        ]
    )

    sleep(5)

    try:
        yield 1
    finally:
        p.kill()


page_loaded_js = '() => !document.body.textContent.includes("Running...") \
    && !document.body.textContent.includes("Loading...")'

def test_import_click_no_input(page: Page):

    page.wait_for_function(page_loaded_js)
    page.get_by_role("button", name="Import").click()
    page.wait_for_function(page_loaded_js)
    expect(page.get_by_text("Not found")).to_be_visible()
```

The SOAP request is made after the Import button is clicked and a certain response is expected from the server. I've mocked the response in unit tests but can't get it to work for the e2e tests.